# Create PDF file thru an online text editor and save it directly to the web server filesystem ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, tinymce, itext, memorystream

Hi my question is this possible?
I am currently using TinyMce and Itextsharp to create a pdf file but my problem is when I save it requires to be saved in the client's pc which is not needed I only want to saved it directly to the web server file system for the user to download anytime he wants.
so this is what I want to do.

**type text in tinymce editor > create pdf > save pdf to the webserver instead of the client's pc > download the pdf anytime the user wants.**

I have read about File and Memory streams but I fear they only save the data to client-side and requires the user to download it to pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the technical details, I don't see why this wouldn't be possible.

There are many content management systems who integrate an HTML editor into their web site so that people can create simple HTML that is then submitted to the server to be stored as HTML in the CMS.

You need to do something similar: people should submit the HTML, and then you should write an iTextSharp  application that runs on the server (which is much easier than having it run on the client). This application will create a PDF that you can then store on the server. (Extra hint: I would store the original HTML as an embedded file into the PDF.)

Actually, this demo is doing more or less what you need: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

The end users creates some HTML. This HTML is submitted to the server. On the server, iText creates a PDF, but instead of saving it on its file system, the application sends it to the browser. It's only a matter of changing the output stream.

Right now, you're using `Response.OutputStream`. Instead of this output stream, you need to use a `FileStream` to write to the file to the hard disk (to a folder that can be accessed by the application server).

Comment: thank you sir that Filestream struck a lightbulb inside me. I keep on checking the path and realize that it was hidden in the solution explorer all along that's why I can't see it.

Comment: Well, that's what StackOverflow is for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use the iTextSharp to create the pdf.

```
string filePath = "~/Content/Pdf/Test.pdf"
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test"));
doc.Close();
```